# Python datetime rejects 29 February

Tags: python, datetime

I am using Python 3.11 on Windows 11
I get the following result:

```
d = 'Mon 29 Feb'
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%a %d %b')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%a %d %b')
  File "C:\Users\pskipwith\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\_strptime.py", line 579, in     _strptime_datetime
    return cls(*args)
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

but if I add the year, say 2016, it goes through without error:

```
d = 'Mon 29 Feb 2016'
datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%a %d %b %Y')
datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 29, 0, 0)
```

Can this be correct behaviour?

Comment: Thanks to you, I now know that the default year for datetime is 1900 and that it's not a leap year ! :D

Answer (score 7):

## Default year 1900 is not a leap year

You can read in the documentation [datetime>footnotes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#id8):

> Passing datetime.strptime('Feb 29', '%b %d') will fail since 1900 is not a leap year.

```py
d = 'Mon 28 Feb'
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%a %d %b').year)
# 1900
```

Comment: Of course, this brings up the usual reminder that while leap years are normally every 4 years, there is an exception for years divisible by 100 but not by 400.